# Passing URL parameters to a nested serializer

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers, one of which is nested:

```
class PaperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Paper


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    papers = PaperSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        source='paper_set'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

I want to get a list of Authors which shows only their **published** Papers (Boolean field exists on the model).

I would like to call the API like `/api/v1/authors/?show_published_only=true`.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging around, I discovered that you can pass the context from the ViewSet to the Serializer:

**views.py**

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
    filter_fields = (
        'show_published_only',
    )

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}
```

Now, create a new serializer `FilteredPaperSerializer` which inherits from `serializers.ListSerializer`, then override the `to_representation()` method to filter the queryset:

**serializers.py**

```
class FilteredPaperSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        # Get the parameter from the URL
        show_published_only = self.context['request'].query_params['show_published_only']

        data = data.filter(is_published=show_published_only)
        return super(FilteredPaperSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    papers = FilteredPaperSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        source='paper_set'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

**NB:** Don't forget to convert the fetched URL parameter to a Boolean or relevant data type for your model, I neglected to do it in the write-up above.